# Define metadescription

Tags: php, function, meta

I have the following code that creates the meta-description. I'm getting a 0 as meta-description when trying to add a text after the `$info['desc']`.

The original code is

```
function apply_meta($info) {
if (isset($info['desc']) && !empty($info['desc'])) {
    define('META_DESC', $info['desc']);
}
```

What I did is :

```
function apply_meta($info) {
if (isset($info['desc']) && !empty($info['desc'])) {
    define('META_DESC', $info['desc'] + 'my text. Read more about ' + $info['desc'] );
}
```

Comment: What is the actual question? Are you sure `define()` for your purpose?

Comment: Glad I could help! If you're happy with one of the answers, please click the checkmark outline to "accept" it so the respondent gets credit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Period (.) is used in PHP to concat the strings. Replace your + sign with period like this:

```
function apply_meta($info) {
if (isset($info['desc']) && !empty($info['desc'])) {
    define('META_DESC', $info['desc'] . 'my text. Read more about ' . $info['desc'] );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP doesn't use + to concatenate strings, it uses a period. Replace your plus signs with periods and it should work.